# Inner div being pushed out of parent div

Tags: css, html

I´m trying to put the navigation bar in the header div but its being pushed out of it.. so the navigation bar is appearing in the center of the page.
Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks for the help!

Here´s my **HTML**

```
 <body>
        <div class="fondo">
            <div class="header"> <!--barra de navegacion -->
                <div class="logo">
                    <object data="/Users/MaxRuizTagle/Desktop/guardado por illustrator/been.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="logo">
                            <!--[if lte IE 8 ]-->
                        <img src="/Users/MaxRuizTagle/Desktop/guardado por illustrator/images/been.png" alt="Logo"/>
                            <!--[endif]-->
                    </object>
                </div>

                    <div class="container">

                        <div class="sixteen columns">
                            <ul id="nav">
                                <li><a href=""> HOME</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">SPEISEKARTE</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">RESERVIERUNG</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">LOCATION</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">JOBS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">KONTAKT</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">DJs</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="footer">
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        </body>
```

and **CSS**

```
body {
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            height:1000px;
            font-family: 'Myriad Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .fondo {
            min-width:100%;
            min-height: 80%;
            background-image: url('../Img/imagenes/fotoportada.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
            position: absolute;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }
        .header {
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100px;
            max-height:100px;
            background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
        }

        .footer {
            background-color:rgb(28,92,144);
            min-width: 100%;
            height:400px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
        }



        ul#nav {
            margin: 147px 0 0 120px;
            float: left;
        }

        ul#nav li{

            margin-right: 30px;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            display: inline;    
        }


        .logo {
            max-width: 20%;

        }

        .logo object, img {
            min-width:100%;
            float:left;
            position: relative;
            top:-25px;    
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set a top `margin` of `147px` to the `ul#nav` element. that's why it's pushed down. change that and set a proper value.

```css
ul#nav {
  /* margin: 147px 0 0 120px; */
  float: left;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/wucov/1/edit)**.

Comment: thanks you i didnt saw that .. but its steel showing out of the header div  :/

Comment: Did you check the jsbin demo? the navigation is displayed inside of the header: http://jsbin.com/wucov/2/edit (the orange box in the demo)

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing the element down to the middle of the page with margin, and your `float:left` is causing it to appear below the logo.

Try this CSS:

```
    ul#nav {
      margin-left: 20%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same kind of issue, turned out to be an extra closed  tag without an opening tag.